# Views - comprehensive source for studying?

Tags: views

Making my first website I've been playing a lot with Views recently but I am still struggling to master both Relationships and Contextual filters. I've watched the video trainings provided in the views' section as well as passed through the docs but I think that's not deeper enough. Could you guys suggest some source for studying on this topic - a book, video series, web page ... ?
Much appreciated :)
BR, Ivan

Comment: Hi Ivan, welcome to Drupal Answers. I'm afraid that _"Requests for tutorials, and other online resources"_ are not considered to be the right format of question for this site so I'll need to close this. Happily it seems you have a good answer already though, which is great news. For a bit more information please see [the FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) which describes what types of questions are appropriate for Drupal Answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By all means - start the Taming the Beast screencast series by NodeOne: http://nodeone.se/en/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-1-overview